# Creating a dictionary using indices of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What is the most efficient way to create a dictionary from a string/list? For example, if I have a list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, how would I create the dictionary for which the elements of the list are the keys, and the indices are the values? How it would look like for the above list: `{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumerate()` will return the elements and their indexes, you can use this in a dictionary comprehension.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
d = {value: index for index, value in enumerate(l)}
```

Comment: cool, is there a faster way to do this, like in O(n) time? I'm just curious...

Comment: This is O(n) complexity

Comment: oops, made a typo. I mean O(1) complexity

Comment: No, that's impossible. It always takes at least O(n) complexity to create a dictionary containing n elements.

Comment: It takes at least O(n) time to create any container with n elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
lista = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
dictionary = {}

n = 0
for el in lista:
    dictionary[el] = n
    n += 1
```